# Mongoid custom setter not working on embedded field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have complex Mongoid documents that are created in another system that I want to be able to edit a field buried in the document tree.  I dont want to create embedded models, I would prefer to use custom setter/getters.  The getter is working fine but the setter is not, it appears to work, no errors, but the data never gets saved to the database. Following the example on the [Mongoid site](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields) here is my model;

```
class MyModel

  field :name
  
  def subfield
    self.attributes["value"][0]["value"]
  end

  def subfield=(array)
    p 'Setting.. '
    self.attributes["value"][0]["value"]=array
    p '.. done!'
  end

end


>> mod = MyModel.last
#<MyModel _id: 55566a8b53307b2c3f99737d, name: "nonlinear_avm">
>> mod.subfield 
[1, 2]
>> mod.subfield = [3,4]
"Setting.. "
".. done!"
[3,4]
>> mod.save! 
true
>> mod.reload 
#<MyModel _id: 55566a8b53307b2c3f99737d, name: "nonlinear_avm">
>> mod.subfield 
[1, 2]
```

As you can see, the field never gets saved.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing `values` behind Mongoid's back so it doesn't know that you've changed anything. This:

```
self.attributes["value"][0]["value"]=array
```

alters the `value` attribute in-place so the array itself doesn't change, only its content changes. You should be able to get around this problem by manually marking the field as dirty:

```
def subfield=(array)
  value_will_change!
  self.attributes["value"][0]["value"]=array
end
```

That should get `value` to show up in the `changed_attributes` list and that should convince Mongoid to update it in the database when you `save`.

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method error on 'value_will_change! '  Do I need to include something to get that method?

Comment: Do you have a `field :value` in the model?

Comment: No, it is a dynamic field, and I've added  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

Comment: Could you add a `field` declaration for it? Either that or you'd probably need to replace the whole `value` attribute with a different array so that `self.attributes['value'].object_id` will change; this would be the `write_attribute` approach that the docs mention.

Comment: Thanks @mu   I added a field declaration for `value` and now the `value_will_change!` method works which forces the dirty flag.  I still have issues with key names containing `.` somewhere in the tree, but this gets me going in the right direction!

Comment: Dots inside property names with MongoDB? Wow. That's just asking for trouble. I'm guessing that you can't fix those names to fit MongoDB naming conventions better.

Comment: The documents are serialized R linear models.  Dots are common in R variable names.  uhgg!  They save from R okay, but obviously Mongoid does not like them.

Comment: MongoDB (not just Mongoid) really wants to use dots to separate components in nested paths, this seems to be a fairly popular topic: https://www.google.ca/#q=mongodb+dots+in+keys